# Angular component Design pattern or principle

Tags: angular, design-patterns, primeng, solid-principles, design-principles

How should we get rid of if else/switch statement - business logic for specific components?

For example, I want to display data in my table and I have created 2 components. 1st is Smart component - table wrapper and 2nd is dumb component - table component.

```html
<table-wrapper> smart component which is responsible to load the data and pass the data to my embedded component
   <table></table> dumb component which takes just input data and then output for emit the events
</table-wrapper>
```

As per Single responsibility principles, one component should do a single task, not multiple tasks. I have 100 tables and use this single component to render and display the data. In some tables, I have a couple of conditions for different scenarios which I don't want to write in my component which becomes very large files in the future and we end up writing an if-else/switch statement. How should we manage this type of additional separate logic for any component which is not responsible for a specific component. I am not quite sure if I need to follow any design pattern or principle.

Comment: Ideally smart component is responsible to fetch the data and feed to its subsides. Dumb component should be receiving and perform what it intend to do. Keep it simple use Input and Output to access dumb. If you dont like that to do. Use templateRef to take dumb component as Input to render. Or try using ngComponentOutlet to bring dumb component to render dynamically. My advice is, alway keep things simple since everyone in your team has to understand the logic